# Темы вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Господа хорошие, пожалуйста (((
Ищу вот такую тему вордпресс , с таким как здесь https://acrosuites.com/ курсором ....
ну или чтото подобное, помогите пожалуйста найти, пожалуйста, пожалуйста,пожалуйста

Мне нужна именно тема, там и другие фишки годные были ..

Comment: потому что мне в репозитории попалась эта тема(ну не именно эта, очень похожая) ,  с таким курсором, галереей .... очень понравилась а я ненароком закладки удалил

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужен такой же курсор, то просто через css подключите его на свой сайт

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  cursor: url("https://acrosuites.com/wp-content/themes/webdesign-Abouthotelier-theme-2/assets/img/cursor.png"), default;
}
```

вместо ссылки можете указать файл своего курсора

Comment: мне в репозитории попалась эта тема(ну не именно эта, очень похожая) , с таким курсором, галереей .... очень понравилась а я ненароком закладки удалил. МНЕ НУЖНА ИМЕННО ТЕМА

Comment: тема кстомная, но на основе [вот этих шаблонов](https://abouthotelier.com/en/template_websites), называется `webdesign-Abouthotelier-theme-2`